# Plotting a lognormal distribution of stock price

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I have the daily price data of a particular stock from 2000-01-01 to 2018-12-31 from Yahoo. I understand that the daily percentage change of a stock price follows a Normal Distribution and hence I have done the following:

```
df['pct_change'] = df['Adj Close'].pct_change()
df = df.dropna()

# Plot normal distribution of daily returns
mu = df['pct_change'].mean()
std = df['pct_change'].std()
x = np.linspace(mu - 5*std, mu + 5*std,100)
plt.plot(x, stats.norm.pdf(x, mu, std))
plt.show()
```

Now, I want to plot the price of the stock with a lognormal distribution, but I am very confused with the `stats.lognorm.pdf()` function and the parameters to include. Since the log of price is normally distributed, should I create a new column of the log of `Adj Price` column in the original data frame? Here is the `head()` of the data frame if it helps. Thanks.

```
            High       Low      Open     Close       Volume        Adj Close  \
Date                                                                         
2000-01-03  4.017857  3.631696  3.745536  3.997768  133949200.0   3.488905   
2000-01-04  3.950893  3.613839  3.866071  3.660714  128094400.0   3.194754   
2000-01-05  3.948661  3.678571  3.705357  3.714286  194580400.0   3.241507   
2000-01-06  3.821429  3.392857  3.790179  3.392857  191993200.0   2.960991   
2000-01-07  3.607143  3.410714  3.446429  3.553571  115183600.0   3.101249   

              pct_change  
Date                    
2000-01-03    0.088754  
2000-01-04   -0.084310  
2000-01-05    0.014634  
2000-01-06   -0.086539  
2000-01-07    0.047368
```

Comment: What is `stats`? You should show relevant import statements in your examples.

Comment: @wwii: It's `scipy.stats` (the question is tagged `scipy`). The question isn't clear to me though: Are you trying to fit a log normal to your price (and which one of the prices?), disregarding time entirely?

Comment: @fuglede: I am trying to fit the 'Adj Price', since I want to show the prices follow a lognormal distribution. Is this how I use the lognormal dist? Or is the correct way to interpret is as: given the mean and std from 'Adj Price', a price x will follow a certain lognormal dist?

Comment: If you want to determine whether or not the data follows a certain distribution, in addition to whatever statistical tests fit the bill for your purposes, you may also want to have a Q-Q plot; they tend to be easier to read than just plotting the fitted distribution against the data.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that you want to estimate the paramters for your log-normal using MLE, and that you're interested in the values of `df.Close` in particular, you can do so using `lognorm.fit`:

```
shape, location, scale = stats.lognorm.fit(df.Close)
```

From there, you can plot the distribution just as you do for your normal distribution case, obtaining your densities through

```
stats.lognorm.pdf(x, s=shape, loc=location, scale=scale)
```

Comment: Should it be stats.lognorm.fit(df) or stats.lognorm.fot(df['Adj Price'])? Since I am interested in plotting the log norm distribution of adjusted price?

Comment: It should be `stats.lognorm.fit(df['Adj Price'])` then.